# Library to detect facepoints from .jpg in Android

Tags: android, face-detection, face-recognition

I am making an app to calculate facial symmetry by comparing distance between points to golden ratio.So far,I tried

1. hardware.Camera.Face - gives face bounds and co-ords of eye and mouth centre.
2. media.FaceDetector.Face - it only gives face bounds and eye location.

I need face bounds PLUS eye,nose,mouth and ear bounds.

If anyone have used a library which can detect face points in image, please mention the name. Also, in your opinion how fast and accurate is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV might be a good consideration, have a look at this example, http://romanhosek.cz/android-eye-detection-and-tracking-with-opencv/

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV is a very powerful library for doing all kinds of face recognition and face detection work! Check it out

Answer (score 1):

You might also try the new Android face detector, which detects several facial landmarks:

https://developers.google.com/vision/detect-faces-tutorial